# Which functions are in $C_0^\infty$, except for the Bump function

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples

We all know the standard example for a function in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, namely
\begin{align}
\Phi(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{ -\frac{1}{1 - x^2}} & \mbox{ for } |x| < 1\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
However, I have never heard of a different function in $C_0^\infty$. Of course, you can do a rescaling of the given function or introduce other minor changes (I assume without a proof, that you could replace the $x^2$ with $x^4$). But are there any types of functions in $C_0^\infty$. I would be very happy to hear some examples or references.

Thanks!

(Also, if you can come up with better tags, please feel free to edit.)

Comment: You can take convolution of any $f$ support in $B\subset\subset \Omega$ with a smooth bump function to get another bump function too.

Comment: Any smooth function multiplied by $\Phi$.

Comment: See the links I give in my answer at [How many smooth functions are non-analytic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94634/how-many-smooth-functions-are-non-analytic) for a fairly thorough discussion and list of references.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I feel stupid for not realizing, that I could just combine $\phi$ with another function. If any of you would take the time to write your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks!