# Question about the Cardinality of functions that are continuous everywhere but differential nowhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I know that on a closed interval, for example, $C[a,b]$ has the same cardinality as $R$. However, can we know the cardinality of functions that are continuous everywhere but differential nowhere($S$) on an interval $[a,b]$? By Baire's theorem, we know that these functions form a second category. Can we construct a one-to-one mapping showing that $S$ has the same cardinality as $R$?

Any materials to refer to are highly appreciated.

Comment: The class of continuous functions altogether has cardinality $\lvert\Bbb R\rvert$, and given any function in your set there are $\lvert\Bbb R\rvert$ many such functions by considering $\lambda f$ for $\lambda\ne0$.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with Baire's theorem. We can build a one-to-one mapping from this set to $R \times R$?

Comment: The map $f\mapsto \left.f\right\rvert_{\Bbb Q}$ is an injection into $\Bbb R^{\Bbb Q}\cong 2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\cong\Bbb R$. You can do everything with Cantor-Bernstein, if that qualifies as "constructing".

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio: Perhaps simpler, at least it seems to me, is that given any such function $f,$ each of the continuum many functions $f + \lambda$ is such a function, where $\lambda$ ranges over the real numbers (and $\lambda = 0$ is also OK). Indeed, by restricting $\lambda$ to belong to the open interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon),$ we get continuum many functions within an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f$ (sup norm), and with a bit more work (such as is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94706/13130)), we can get continuum many functions within **any** $\epsilon$ ball in $C[a,b].$